# GUI.Button issue prints each button twice to the screen, once with my custom style, and once without

Tags: user-interface, button, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Hi I have created a simple menu in Unity but I wanted to create my own style for colour/fonts.

However for some reason it prints each button twice to the screen, once with my custom style, and once without.

this is the code I have used:

```
if(menu){


if (GUI.Button(Rect(Screen.width/2 - 50, Screen.height/2, 100, 30), "Start Game", customGuiStyle)){

Application.LoadLevel ("Level 1");
}


if (GUI.Button(Rect(Screen.width/2 - 50, Screen.height/2 + 30, 100, 30), "Options", customGuiStyle)){


menu = false;
options = true;
}


if (GUI.Button(Rect(Screen.width/2 - 50, Screen.height/2 + 90, 100, 30), "Quit", customGuiStyle)){


Application.Quit();
}
}
```

I have no idea why it is showing two texts, heres a screen shot of exactly what I mean...[image]

Comment: Possibly a better fit for: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: sorry mate, I didn't know where else to ask. Ill post it on there and remove it from here! thanks anyway

Comment: It's probably something that could remain here as it does relate to programming but you might find people over at Game Dev who have specific UNITY knowledge :)

Comment: Hi. I think I know it. The same Script is assigned to different gameobject. Just check it in the inspector. You will find it I hope.